# Passing today's date in Gatling Body using session.set but no success

Tags: scala, gatling

I am trying to pass today's date in Gatling Body using session.set but no success

I have below code where using joda-time(https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)  timestampfeeder variable is set

```
class gamekeeper extends BaseSimulation {
  val  timestampFeeder: String = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").print(DateTime.now())

  exec { session => session.set( "TimestampFeeder", timestampFeeder )}

  val createPrivateEvent ={
    exec(
      http("Create Event As WER")
      .post("https://api.cloud/" + {Env} + "/silve-griffin-service/graphql")
      .headers(header)
      .body(ElFileBody("<filename>")) 
      .check(status.in(200,201))
      .check(bodyString.saveAs("EventAsWER_Response"))
      .check(jsonPath(path="$.data.createEvent.id")
        .saveAs(key="EventId")
      )
    )
    .exec { session => session.set("NEW_ID", session("EventId").as[String]) }
    .exec{session=>println(session);session}
     //.pause(40,50)
 }

 val scenario4 = scenario("Full GameKeeper tests“)
   .exec(createPrivateEvent)

 setUp(

    scenario4.inject(
      constantConcurrentUsers(userCount) during(testDuration))
      .protocols(httpProtocol)
    )
    .maxDuration(testDuration)

}
```

Here are the contents  of createeventasWERwithcurrentdatetime.txt

```
        {
      "query": "mutation createEvent($input: CreateEventInput!) {\n createEvent(input: $input) {\n ...EventFields\n __typename\n }\n}\n\nfragment EventFields on Event {\n id\n status\n title\n format\n limitedSet\n rulesEnforcementLevel\n pairingType\n entryFee {\n amount\n currency\n __typename\n }\n venue {\n id\n name\n latitude\n longitude\n address\n timeZone\n phoneNumber\n emailAddress\n __typename\n }\n capacity\n description\n scheduledStartTime\n estimatedEndTime\n latitude\n longitude\n address\n timeZone\n phoneNumber\n emailAddress\n shortCode\n __typename\n}",
      "variables": {
        "input": {
          "organizationId": "14540",
          "latitude": 47.66499,
          "longitude": -122.38043,
          "phoneNumber": "206-523-9605",
          "emailAddress": "test@gameot.com",
          "title": "PerfTestServicesEvent",
          "format": "DRAFT",
          "pairingType":"SWISS",
          "limitedSet": "CORE2020",
          "rulesEnforcementLevel": "CASUAL",
          "entryFeeAmount": 500,
          "entryFeeCurrency": "USD",
          "venueId": null,
          "capacity": 8,
          "description": "test",
          "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
          "scheduledStartTime": ${TimestampFeeder},
          "estimatedEndTime": "2020-02-15T16:00Z"
        }
      }
    }
```

Seems No success in value substitution ,why session.set is not able to replace the value of TimestampFeeder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your variable setting doesn't work is that the exec to run that session function isn't chained to or called by anything else - it's just defined in the middle of the gamekeeper class.

You also seem to be confused about feeders - unless you're using the gatling construct of this name, it's probably best to call it something else.

You can easily get this working by having a session function that sets the date and including it at the start of the scenario.

```
val scenario4 = scenario("Full GameKeeper tests“)
   .exec(session => session.set("TimestampFeeder",DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").print(DateTime.now()) 
   .exec(createPrivateEvent)
```

I don't think you can used your existing TimestampFeeder val as it's only going to get set once at the start of the run - you'd have to make it a function if you want to structure things that way.

Comment: great explanation